# Redirect multiple users at once rails.

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, websocket

I have a web app built in Rails.

In it a selection of the users are looking at a classroom page. When one of the users hits a button on the page, I want to redirect anyone that's looking at that page elsewhere. I'm looking for a simple solution for this. I don't need lots of things to update on the page. I just want when one user clicks a button.. for it to redirect everyone looking at the page elsewhere.

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated. I'm using Rails 4.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is possible, but your main problem would be on how will you detect whoever is seeing that page

Comment: I would recommend Pusher- as (for me) this is the easiest way to implement Websocket functionality.

I would have though the simplest way would be to trigger an event via Pusher once the button is clicked. You can then update either certain elements or the entire page contents for all others connected clients.

Comment: @Lymuel that isn't a problem because in the classroom page when someone opens it, you have to be a user. So I can just add the user to an array of people that are in the classroom.

Comment: @BenHawker thanks for the recommendation Ben. I'll look into pusher right now.